# How to test class method that takes input?

Tags: python, unit-testing, automated-tests, pytest

So I have a class method that asks for a group size via user input;

```
def set_group_size(self):
    valid_input = False
    while not valid_input:
        response = input('Group Size: ')
        if isinstance(response, int):
            self.group_size = response
            valid_input = True
```

But am struggling about the best way to test this?  I essentially want to ensure that the value of self.group_size is an integer, and also the integer that got input the user function.

I see mocks are pretty popular for what I've been searching for, so this is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working that well because I can change some logic in the method itself and tests still pass;

```
def test_it_chooses_group_size(self):
    self.together.set_group_size = MagicMock(return_value=6)
    assert self.together.set_group_size() == 6
    assert type(self.together.set_group_size()) == int
```

I am seeming to struggle wrapping my head around the concept of testing a method that takes user input and sets that to be a class attribute value.

Comment: Don't use `input` with Python 2, as your code implies. (Python 3's `input` *always* returns a `str`, and Python 2's `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`, so who knows what `input` might return or even *do*.

Comment: I am using Python3.  I should always use `raw_input()`?

Comment: If you are using Python 3, then `isinstance(response, int)` will *never* be true.

Comment: @chepner, got it.  I figured out that was an issue, and answered my own question below.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had some other issues with the method itself (input was a string, so condition was never met), but I ended up getting it to work as I'd expect;

```
def set_group_size(self):
    valid_input = False
    while not valid_input:
        r = input('Group Size: ')
        if r.isdigit():
            self.group_size = int(r)
            valid_input = True
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid number')
```

Test:

```
def test_it_chooses_group_size(self):
    with mock.patch('builtins.input', return_value='6'):
        self.together.set_group_size()
        assert self.together.group_size == 6
        assert type(self.together.group_size) == int
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code to make it more testable (and simply *try* to make `response` into an `int` instead of testing to see if `int(response)` would succeed).

```
def set_group_size(self, input=input):
    while True:
        response = input('Group Size: ')
        try:
            self.group_size = int(response)
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass  # Try again
```

To test, pass a function that doesn't read from standard input, but from some pre-defined source of data.

```
def make_input(stream):
    def _(prompt):
        return next(stream).rstrip("\n")
    return _

def test_it_chooses_group_size(self):
    my_input = make_input(stringio.StringIO("foo\nbar\n3")
    self.together.set_group_size(my_input)
    assert self.together.group_size == 3

def test_no_int_received(self):
    my_bad_input = make_input(stringio.StringIO("foo\n")
    old_group_size = self.together.group_size
    try:
        self.together.set_group_size(my_bad_input)
    except StopIteration:
        assert True  # Expected outcome, since input contains no int
    else:
        # This shouldn't be reachable; set_group_size has to
        # either terminate upon seeing an `int`, run forever, or raise
        # an uncaught StopIteration exception.
        assert False
```

The only thing this doesn't test is if `set_group_size` will give you unlimited chances to input an integer, but that's not a testable property anyway.